# Convert.ToSingle() from double in vb.net returns wrong value

Tags: vb.net, double

Here is my question :

If we have the following value

```
0.59144706948010461
```

and we try to convert it to Single we receive the next value:

```
0.591447055
```

As you can see this is not that we should receive. Could you please explain how does this value get created and how can I avoid this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As you can see this is not that we should receive.

Why not? I strongly suspect that's the closest `Single` value to the `Double` you've given.

From the documentation for [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), having fixed the typo:

> All floating-point numbers have a limited number of significant digits, which also determines how accurately a floating-point value approximates a real number. A `Single` value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

Your `Double` value is 0.5914471 when limited to 7 significant digits - and so is the `Single` value you're getting. Your original `Double` value isn't *exactly* 0.59144706948010461 either... the *exact* values of the `Double` and `Single` values are:

- `Double`: 0.5914470694801046146693579430575482547283172607421875
- `Single`: 0.591447055339813232421875

It's important that you understand a bit about how binary floating point works - see my articles on [binary floating](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) point and [decimal floating](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) point for more background.

Comment: I'm not sure but I thought that converting also includes rounding. So for me it's pretty weird why we get this value. Again, I'm not sure, just some math-based thoughts

Comment: @Viaches: Yes, it includes rounding (it has to - you're losing information) - but this is rounding in *binary*, not decimal.

Comment: ok, so for double 0.591447055 and double 0.591447071 single would be the same. for me it's pretty..weird i guess. but..i mean can we somehow get different single values for this doubles?

Comment: @Viaches: I would have to try those two `Double` values - it may well be that the next highest `Single` is closer to 0.591447071. It's not clear what you mean by "different single values" - I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Viaches Unit conversions have the same issues. 6' or 7' rounded to the nearest meter are both 2m. 71 and 72 degrees F both correspond to 22 degrees C.

Comment: The next single up is 0.5914471149444580078125. 0.591447071 does round down to 0.591447055339813232421875.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Thanks. I keep meaning to create a little web page where you can enter a number and it will show you all kinds of useful information like this (including the binary representations etc).

Comment: It may be very stupid idea but.. i need something like next: if i have double value 0.5914471 and convert it to single as a result to have a single 0.591447071 but not 0.591447055. This is crazy thing i want to have but.. i have vb6 version of project and it seems to me that it casts value like 0.5914471 but not like in vb.net. again, this is only an idea

Comment: @Viaches: No, you can't do this. Because 0.591447071 simply isn't representable as a `Single`. You're asking it to preseve more significant digits than it's capable of. If you want more information, use a bigger type.

Answer (score 0):

When converting from double to float you're also rounding. The result should be the single-precision number that is closest to the number you are rounding.

That is exactly what you're getting here.

Floating-point numbers between 0.5 and 1 are of the form `n / 2^24` where `n` is between `2^23` and `2^24`.

```
0.59144706948010461... = 9922835.23723472274456576... / 2^24
```

so the closest single-precision floating-point number is

```
9922835 / 2^24 = 0.5914470553...
```